# Google Places API REQUEST_DENIED (With valid API Key)

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am getting REQUEST_DENIED error when i try to use the API and simulate different locations. The sample parameters from the API docs works but when I use a different Lat and Long coord, it bounces as REQUEST_DENIED. It was working about a week ago. Please what can I do?

code in php:

......////

```
                  $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=".$latitude.",
                  ".$longitude."&radius=100&sensor=false&key=".$key."";

                   // Open the Curl session
                      $session = curl_init($url);

                      // If it's a POST, put the POST data in the body
                      //if ($_POST['path']) {
                          $postvars = '';
                          while ($element = current($_GET)) {
                              $postvars .= urlencode(key($_GET)).'='.urlencode($element).'&';
                              next($_GET);
                          }
                          curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                          curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
                      //}

                      // Don't return HTTP headers. Do return the contents of the call
                      curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                      curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                      curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
                      //curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.urldecode($password));

                      // Make the call
                      $json = curl_exec($session);
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are using the key in your code?

Comment: Hi Quinma, I have added the php code now. Please have a look